# Strange struts2 behavior

Tags: struts2

There is something strange happening.

Param interceptor is the one in charge to take parameters strings values from the request and put them in the java property of my action.

Some defaults type converters exist (primary types, Date, Map, Array)

And I tried to put a string parameter in a BigDecimal.  Strangely... it works but how ? I am pretty sure that the BigDecimal converters does not exist and has to be implemented by the framework user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am correct it is using the default BigDecimal parsing.have a look at [DefaultTypeConverter](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/conversion/impl/DefaultTypeConverter.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I know this class, it is used to create your own type converters.

Comment: I read struts 2 in Action which is quite a good book comparing to some others. The list of default converters is this one :

Comment: String, boolean/Boolean, char/Character, int/Integer, float/Float, long/Long, double/Double, Date(in a SHORT format), array, List and Map

Comment: But I accept your answer and let us say that it exists for BigDecimal too.

Comment: `DefaultTypeConverter` does indeed handle `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`.